# How to combine comments from level 3 to level 2

Tags: java

Currently in my database there is data of posts and its comments. Each post will have many comments and comments can be level 2 3 4... Currently, I can query to get the comments level 1 of the article. And now I want my comment to have only 2 levels, level 1 and level 2 and its sub-levels

```
// Here is a list of comments including all levels
        List<DiscussionReplyRS> discussionHierarchy = contentDAO.getListDiscussionReply(discussionId, spaceId).stream()
                .filter(Objects::nonNull)
                .map(DiscussionMapper::toDiscussionReplyRS)
                .collect(Collectors.toList());

        // Consider this the father of level 1 comments
        Optional<DiscussionReplyRS> discussionChild = discussionHierarchy.stream()
                .filter(dc -> dc.getReplyToPostId() == 0).findFirst();

        if (!discussionChild.isPresent()) {
            discussionHierarchy.remove(discussionChild);

            // These are level 1 comments
            List<DiscussionReplyRS> discussionReplies = discussionHierarchy.stream()
                    .filter(dr -> Objects.equals(dr.getReplyToPostId(), discussionChild.get().getDiscussionReplyId()))
                    .collect(Collectors.toList());

            discussionHierarchy.remove(discussionReplies);

            // This will be the list of comments for the rest of the levels
            List<DiscussionReplyRS> discussionReplyChilds = new ArrayList<>(discussionHierarchy);

            // The rest of the comments I leave as comments of 1st graders
            //I don't know what to do next
        }
```

Comment: You might want to share your `DiscussionReplyRS` class or how your data looks like.